# Set chrome's "Ask where to save each file before downloading" setting via group policy

Tags: google-chrome, group-policy

I am deploying chrome throughout our domain via group policy.  I want to require that all file downloads ask where to save the file.  There is a setting in chrome to "Ask where to save each file before downloading", but I can't seem to find an appropriate group policy in the policy editor.  Am I missing something, or is there some other way (via group policy) that this can be accomplished?  I've found [this](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/tmUu0jqHHTM/EAlqVy81OqoJ) solution, but that involves editing a file on the computers so that's out of the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Editing a text file on the users' computers shouldn't be "out of the question" -- GP + Logon Scripts + [PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/01/17/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-replace-characters-in-a-text-file.aspx) = Problem solved.

Comment: This is true, I will investigate that option, thanks!